# Node.js / MongoDB / Mongoose: Buffer Comparison

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, buffer

First, a little background:

I'm trying to check to see if an image's binary data has already been saved in Mongo.  Given the following schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var imageSchema = new Schema({
    mime:  String,
    bin: { type: Buffer, index: { unique: true }},
    uses : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Image', imageSchema);
```

...I want to query to see if an image exists, if it does add a reference that my object is using it, and then update it.  If it doesn't, I want to create (upsert) it.

Given the case that it does not exist, the below code works perfectly.  If it does, the below code does not and adds another Image document to Mongo.  I feel like it is probably a comparison issue for the Mongo Buffer type vs node Buffer, but I can't figure out how to properly compare them.  Please let me know how to update the below!  Thanks!

```
Image.findOneAndUpdate({
    mime : contentType,
    bin : image
}, {
    $pushAll : {
        uses : [ myObject._id ]
    }
}, {
    upsert : true
}, function(err, image) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    // !!!image is created always, never updated!!!
});
```

Comment: When did you add the unique index? I spent ages trying to figure out why it was allowing duplicates, restarting mongo and reindexing fixed the issue for me after adding a unique index.

Comment: I had the unique index set in the schema, I thought from the start.  But it is possible I added it after the initial collection was created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mongoose converts Buffer elements destined to be stored to mongodb [Binary](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/binary.html), but it performs the appropriate casts when doing queries.
The expected behavior is also checked in [units tests](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/test/model.querying.test.js#L1703) (also the storage and retrieval of a node.js Buffer).

Are you sure you are passing a node.js Buffer?

In any case I think the best approach to handle the initial problem (check if an image is already in the db) would be storing a strong hash digest (sha1, sha256, ...) of the binary data and check that (using the crypto module).
When querying, as a preliminary test you could also check the binary length to avoid unnecessary computations.

For an example of how to get the digest for your image before storing/querying it:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

...

// be sure image is a node.js Buffer
var image_digest = crypto.createHash('sha256');
image_digest.update(image);
image_digest = image_digest.digest('base64');
```

Comment: Thanks.  The hash works well, can't believe I didn't think of that.  I'll have to do some tests based on those unit tests you provided just for my own edification.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to query for your image by the node.js Buffer that contains the image data. You're right that it's probably an issue between the BSON binary data type and a node Buffer, but does your application really require such a comparison?

Instead, I'd add an imageID or slug field to your schema, add an index to this field, and query on it instead of `bin` in your `findOneAndUpdate` call:

```
var imageSchema = new Schema({
    imageID: { type: String, index: { unique: true }},
    mime:  String,
    bin: Buffer,
    uses : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId}]
});
```

Comment: So if I wanted to ensure the same image couldn't be uploaded twice, even under different filenames, can I use this method?

Comment: If you really don't have any metadata that you could use to uniquely identify images, then you'd have to somehow compare the actual image data. But this would only work if all of the images have the same format. Also, you would probably want some more special purpose tool (that is, not MongoDB) for doing such comparisons, one that understands image formats and perhaps can do comparisons without actually comparing the entire image byte by byte.

Comment: hashing, that was what i was looking for.  Your answer is still valid and helpful, so +1, but the other was exactly what I needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the hash does work, another filter I have used is the exif data for the image.
As this is structured information, if you have a match on exif data, you could then go to the next step of checking for a match on the hash or file size...

heaps of node modules to get the exif data nice and easily for your storage :)
example code to get exif data for node